# Replace a 2D point in one dataframe with a 2D point in another dataframe if the Euclidean between them is the lowest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, euclidean-distance

I have a data frame df1 with two columns V1 and V2 representing two coordinates of a point.

**df1**

```
V1          V2
1.30344679  0.060199021
1.256628917 0.095897457
0.954959945 0.237514922
1.240081297 0.053228255
1.35765432  0.033412217
1.228539425 0.079924064
1.080489363 0.204162117
1.27587021  0.085286683
1.44        0
0.93719247  0.310292371
```

There's another dataframe df2 with two columns C1 and C2 representing two coordinates of a point.

**df2**

```
C1          C2
0.083       0.323657888
1.293934451 0.046950426
1.252872503 0.09000528
0.148131303 0.347930828
```

df1 and df2 have different lengths. In this example, there will be replacements for four points in df1. Essentially, four points in df2 replaces four points in df1 if the Euclidean between them is the lowest.

We can also say, each point in df2 replaces only the closest point in df1. How can we achieve this?

Duplicate issue: The number of digits after decimal is 9. So, I assume the issue of duplicate will not arise (i.e., more than one point in df1 have same Euclidean distance and the distance value is the lowest).  If it arises, we can replace any one of the row at random?

Desired output: revised_df1 of same length as df1 but revised_df1 has four points from df2 replaced.

Comment: So, rewording what you said, you want every point in `df1` replaced with the closest point from `df2`?  Or is it the other way around?  You wrote it both ways.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes

Comment: @Wilian I have made an edit

Comment: Well, hang on.  You don't want ALL the points in `df1` replaced with their closest match in `df2`?  How will you decide which points to replace?

Comment: @TimRoberts if the euclidean distance between the two points is lowest. Essentially, each point in df2 replaces the closest point in df1.

Comment: The first and last points in `df2` are both closest to the last point in `df1`, and neither of them are really very close.  Are you sure you have specified the problem correctly?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, in that case we replace it with the closest ones. We are not concerned about the magnitude.

Comment: That doesn't address the duplicate issue.  The closest points to the four entries in `df2` are #9, #0, #1, and #9.  How will you handle that two entries map to the same point?

Comment: @TimRoberts I couldn't understand that because the number of digits after decimal is 9. So, I assumed the issue of duplicate will not arise. If it arises, can it replace any one of the row at random? I will add this point in the question.

Comment: You're not getting me.  Let's go through each row in `df2`.  The first row is closest to the last row in `df1`.  We set `df1[9] = df2[0]`.  The second row goes into df1[1].  The third row goes into df1[2].  The fourth row (`df2[3]`) is still closest to the last row in df1, `df1[9]`.  Do we replace it AGAIN?  Do we have to track which rows have been replaced already?  That's a tricky problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes. We cannot replace a row twice. We have to keep track of rows.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you share a solution if a solution is replaced twice also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works with the data as lists.  Modifying it to work with a dataframe is an exercise left to the reader.  Honestly, since this needs to be done row by row, it might be better to pull the columns out as lists and convert them back later.

Note that, as I tried to imply above, this does NOT guarantee the "optimal" solution.  For each point in df2, we pick the closest point in df1 that has not already been replaced.  It's quite possible that another choice would result in less TOTAL error.

```
import math

df1 = [
[1.30344679 ,  0.060199021],
[1.256628917,  0.095897457],
[0.954959945,  0.237514922],
[1.240081297,  0.053228255],
[1.35765432 ,  0.033412217],
[1.228539425,  0.079924064],
[1.080489363,  0.204162117],
[1.27587021 ,  0.085286683],
[1.44       ,  0],
[0.93719247 ,  0.310292371]
]

df2 = [
[0.083      ,  0.323657888],
[1.293934451,  0.046950426],
[1.252872503,  0.09000528],
[0.148131303,  0.347930828]
]

def printer(d):
    for row in d:
        print( "%.9f %.9f" % tuple(row) )

def dist(p1,p2):
    return math.sqrt( (p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2 )

# For each point in df2:

print("Before")
printer(df1)

replaced = set()
for p2 in df2:
    # Compute the distance to each point in df1.
    distances = [(dist(p1,p2), i1) for (i1,p1) in enumerate(df1)]
    # Sort them by distance.
    distances.sort()
    # Pick the closest that has not already been replaced.
    top = distances.pop(0)
    while top[1] in replaced:
        top = distances.pop(0)
    # Replace it.
    df1[top[1]] = p2
    replaced.add( top[1] )

print("After")
printer(df1)
```

Output:

```
Before
1.303446790 0.060199021
1.256628917 0.095897457
0.954959945 0.237514922
1.240081297 0.053228255
1.357654320 0.033412217
1.228539425 0.079924064
1.080489363 0.204162117
1.275870210 0.085286683
1.440000000 0.000000000
0.937192470 0.310292371
After
1.293934451 0.046950426
1.252872503 0.090005280
0.148131303 0.347930828
1.240081297 0.053228255
1.357654320 0.033412217
1.228539425 0.079924064
1.080489363 0.204162117
1.275870210 0.085286683
1.440000000 0.000000000
0.083000000 0.323657888
```